# Store object in array in react-native using async-storage

Tags: react-native, arraylist, asyncstorage

I have generated random Qr code using Guid id and I'm saving lasted generated Qr code to async-storage but how do i store every generated random Guid id to async-storage in term of array.
here is the code to generate random id.

```
  let base64Logo = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOEAA..";

  function uuidv4() {
    return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
      var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
      return v.toString(16);
    });
  }
  
AsyncStorage.setItem("id", uuidv4());
console.log(uuidv4());
```

Thank you!

Comment: why not generate multiple "id" . you would be storing somthg like AsyncStorage.setItem(`id_${somevalueIdentifier}`, uuidv4());

Comment: @TheChix how does that work ? I'm using every `uuid` to record data. i need to do get request so that if i'm able to store all `uuid` generated from one device.to async storage then it may help to get history of every random `uuid` generated from that device.

Comment: in case you want to go that route i would advise to store each new entry with "id_<versionNumber>" and create one Asyncstorage item that would keep track of the versionNumber. 
something like :
 `AsyncStorage.setItem('id_5', uuidv4()) `
`AsyncStorage.setItem('versionNumber', 5)`

Answer (score 0):

Convert your array to a string using JSON.stringify on save and back to an array using JSON.parse on read

```
let base64Logo = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOEAA..";


    function uuidv4() {
      return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
        var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
        return v.toString(16);
      });
    }

    // save item in array
    try {
      const myArrayString = await AsyncStorage.getItem('ids'); 
      const myArray = myArrayString !== null?JSON.parse(myArray):[];
      myArray.push(uuidv4())
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('ids', JSON.stringify(myArray));
    } catch (error) {
      // Error saving data
    }

    // when you want to retrieve array 
    try {
      const myArray = await AsyncStorage.getItem('ids');
      if (myArray !== null) {
        // We have data!!
        console.log(JSON.parse(myArray));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Error retrieving data
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting syntax error `cannot use keyword 'await' outside an async function`

Comment: make the function async https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

Comment: async function hello() { return "Hello" }; for arrow functions:  let hello = async () => { return "Hello" };

Comment: I did but it store only one latest data in array. I want to store every random id to array list. `Array [
  "a7dbb075-7ebf-4bd5-9538-7ac171f27ba8",
]`

Comment: try to console "myArray" , check this condition is working myArrayString !== null?JSON.parse(myArray):[];

Comment: its shows nothing when i do console `console.log('array',myArray);`